# My program for div(4,2) should return (0, true) and div(4,3) should return (1, false) is giving error

Tags: go

My program for div(4,2) should return (0, true) and div(4,3) should return (1, false).

```
package main

import "fmt"

func div(a int, b int) (int, bool) {
    if a%b == 0 {
        c := a % b
        return c, true
    } else {
        c := a % b
        return c, true
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(div(4, 2)) // should return (0, true)
    fmt.Println(div(4, 3)) // should return (1, false)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/NyiGmd03SGE

Output:

```
0 true
1 true
```

Comment: Giving Following error

Comment: `ture`: is this a typo or were you supposed to write `true`?

Comment: I assume `ture` is a typo for `true`.  If so, then both branches of the if statement return true. Neither branch returns false.

Comment: If your code is giving an error, it's important to include that error in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func div(a int, b int) (int, bool) {
    if a%b == 0 {
        c := a % b
        return c, true
    } else {
        c := a % b
        return c, false
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(div(4, 2)) // should return (0, true)
    fmt.Println(div(4, 3)) // should return (1, false)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/pEh55lBUFJI

Output:

```
0 true
1 false
```

---

Or simply,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func div(a int, b int) (int, bool) {
    c := a % b
    return c, c == 0
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(div(4, 2)) // should return (0, true)
    fmt.Println(div(4, 3)) // should return (1, false)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/zIZvFMdzZqn

Output:

```
0 true
1 false
```

Comment: Thanks Peter it worked like charm